# My meme command is slow. How do I make it respond faster?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have two meme commands. They have two subreddits and that take random memes from that.

Here is my code

```
sreddits_list = ['dankruto', 'narutomemes']

@bot.command(aliases=['narutomeme', 'narmeme', 'nmeme'])
async def Nmeme(ctx):
  subreddit = await reddit.subreddit(random.choice(sreddits_list))
  all_subs = []

  top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

  async for submission in top:
    all_subs.append(submission)

  random_subs = random.choice(all_subs)
  name = random_subs.title
  url = random_subs.url

  em = discord.Embed(title = name, colour = discord.Colour.random(), timestamp = ctx.message.created_at, url = url)
  em.set_image(url = url)
  await ctx.send(embed = em)


#meme cmd
sreddits2_list = ['memes', 'dankmemes']

@bot.command(aliases=['Meme'])
async def meme(ctx):
  subreddit = await reddit.subreddit(random.choice(sreddits2_list))
  all_subs = []

  top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

  async for submission in top:
    all_subs.append(submission)

  random_subs = random.choice(all_subs)
  name = random_subs.title
  url = random_subs.url

  em = discord.Embed(title = name, colour = discord.Colour.random(), timestamp = ctx.message.created_at, url = url)
  em.set_image(url = url)
  await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

I used praw before this. But then someone told me to use asyncpraw. I tried and it was faster. But it's not enough.

Please tell me how do I make it faster?.
The problem is that the bot takes some time to respond and send the embed.

If you want to test the commands, then join the [Discord Server](https://discord.gg/RDtmjTz87H) and try the commands. (It's just a test server)

1. `-meme`
2. `-nmeme`

If the above link does not work then please use this one

https://discord.gg/RDtmjTz87H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is praw and asyncpraw. As they are not made for getting posts, you shouldn't be using them. You can use [RedditEasy](https://pypi.org/project/redditeasy/) which is 2x faster than praw in getting posts.

Comment: I said that I used to use praw. Then I started using asyncpraw. I will try using RedditEasy. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please show me how to use RedditEasy API and the code as I do not know how to use the Api.

Comment: You can check this example: https://github.com/MakufonSkifto/RedditEasy/blob/main/examples/memes.py. There is an async example in the same folder. @NishilSheth

Comment: I did not understand that GitHub code. It is of asyncio. Can you give me the code for the near version of discord.py API?

Comment: See this hastebin for the command: https://hastebin.com/genovocoda.py

Comment: i tried using that code. however, i get the following error when running the command in discord.

Comment: <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x7fe467da9dc0>

Comment: here is my code


@bot.command()
async def meme(ctx):
  post = redditeasy.AsyncSubreddit(subreddit = 'dankmemes',                              client_id='_azC_VNrBlT2QQ',
                                client_secret = 'fmkDPssImRPnzxhcztvfky3W-hJoD',
                                user_agent = 'memes')

  postoutput = await post.get_post()

  em2 = discord.Embed(title = f'{postoutput.title}')
  url = postoutput.content
  
  em2.(url = url)
  await ctx.send(em2)


i do not any error in the terminal

Comment: You need to do await ctx.send(embed=em2) instead of await ctx.send(em2) @NishilSheth

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have one more thing to ask. Can I like pick posts from 2 subreddits. I mean the api should pick a random subreddit from the list of subreddits given and then pick a random post

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly regarding your bots latency(ping) and the place you are requesting it from. I also recommend you use  the reddit api(json).

Comment: So can I like decrease the latency time. I mean it is actually like between 30-40 ms everytime. Also please tell me the code as I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I really didn't understand. Please just give me the code for this.